# unit test work flow

Tags: python, unit-testing

New to unit test. Try to make sure I understand it correctly.

1> I wrote a module "foo111.py", contains one function "add"

2> I want to test "add'. I create a script called "test_foo111.py"

3> in the test script, I create a "test_add", I call it from the main of the test script (pls see picture below)

4> When I click on "main" of the test_foo111.py, the script run in normal debug mode.

5> only when I click on the "test_add" function, the script run in testing mode.

I thought I'm able to call all the test from the main(imagine I will have more functions in foo111), so that I don't need to run all the test one by one???? I think I must mis-understood something here.. 
step 4
[image: step 4]

step 5
[image: step 5]

Comment: Use a framework - https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: As mentioned, the link above is what you should look at to write proper unittests. Here is a good tutorial to give you more info: docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the unit test framework you need to import it like that:

```
import unittest
```

And your class signature should look like this:

```
class myTestClass (unittest.TestCase):
    def TestName(self):
```